# mingw OpenGL SDL shows only white textures

Tags: opengl, mingw, sdl, cross-compiling

I tried compiling Nehe (http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/texture_mapping/12038/) lesson06 with mingw for Windows using the Linux/SDL version provided in the tutorial.

The Cube is drawn plain white instead of textured. (tested on win7 and also with wine on my development machine)

I can confirm that the texture is loaded by SDL correctly but obviously not into OpenGL.

I also tried generating random noise as texture (no use of SDL_image or SDL_loadBMP), but the Windows build still does not display any textures.

I use Codeblocks under Ubuntu and went through this tutorial http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=Code::Blocks_and_Cross_Compilers to set up my cross compiler.

I believe it is related to the way I compile, but can't make out a source for the error.

Comment: Update your GFX card drivers.

Comment: Did not help. Also: running on wine should use the same driver as the native linux client which renders correctly.

Comment: Are you sure the image loads correctly? Did you check if `textureImage->w` is correct? If it is, please post the relevant rendering code as well.

Comment: @Ben Ruijl: yes the image loads fine into SDL with 256x256 pixels.

Comment: -1 for the lack of relevant information.

Comment: Did you every solve this? I got the exact same problem. Program working fine under Linux, porting it to windows using mingw, and all textures are white.

Comment: @UnixShadow: no I did not, sorry. But If you find any clues/solution please tell me!

Answer (score 1):

I found this question googling for the same problem. Took a day to findout what was going on.

The problem is the resize method that probably recreates the drawing area or so, there could be many programs using the same graphic card, so my guess is that the card releases the textures when this resizing code is running.

Reloading the textures in the resize method helps (on my project) havent tries on nehe lession 6, but it suffered from the same symptoms.

I put my textures raw data into a cache and reloaded them into openGL.

I hope this helps,
Regards Kristoffer.

Answer (score 0):

`glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)`. Texturing is disabled by default.

---

```
#include <SDL/SDL.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glu.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <SDL/SDL_image.h>

#undef main

static int scrWidth = 800;
static int scrHeight = 600;

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);

    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_RED_SIZE, 8);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_GREEN_SIZE, 8);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_BLUE_SIZE, 8);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DEPTH_SIZE, 16);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_SWAP_CONTROL, 0);

    if (SDL_SetVideoMode(scrWidth, scrHeight, 32, SDL_OPENGL) == 0){
        fprintf(stderr, "couldn't set mode %dx%d!\n", 640, 480);
        SDL_Quit();
        return -1;
    }
    glewInit();
    IMG_Init(IMG_INIT_PNG|IMG_INIT_JPG);

    SDL_ShowCursor(SDL_DISABLE);

    glClearColor(0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f);
    glClearDepth(1.0f);

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    GLuint texId = 0;
    glGenTextures(1, &texId);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texId);


    SDL_Surface* tex = IMG_Load("1.png");

    int texW = tex->w, texH = tex->h;
    SDL_LockSurface(tex);

    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);

    int bytesPerPixel = tex->format->BytesPerPixel;

    GLenum texFormat = GL_INVALID_ENUM, pixelFormat = GL_INVALID_ENUM;

    switch(bytesPerPixel){
        case(3):
            texFormat = GL_RGB;
            pixelFormat = texFormat;
            break;
        case(4):
            texFormat = GL_RGBA;
            pixelFormat = texFormat;
            break;
        default:
            fprintf(stderr, "invalid texture format: %d bytes per pixel", bytesPerPixel);
            SDL_FreeSurface(tex);
            SDL_Quit();
            return -1;
            break;
    }

    int expectedPitch = bytesPerPixel*tex->w;
    if (tex->pitch != expectedPitch){
        fprintf(stderr, "invalid surface pitch %d instead of %d", tex->pitch, expectedPitch);
        SDL_FreeSurface(tex);
        SDL_Quit();
        return -1;
    }

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, texFormat, texW, texH, 0, pixelFormat, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, tex->pixels);
    GLenum err = glGetError();
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

    SDL_UnlockSurface(tex);

    SDL_FreeSurface(tex);


    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texId);

    bool running = true;
    while (running){
        SDL_Event event;
        if (SDL_PollEvent(&event)){
            switch(event.type){
                case SDL_QUIT:
                    running = false;
                    break;
            };
        }

        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadIdentity();
        gluOrtho2D(0, scrWidth, scrHeight, 0);

        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glLoadIdentity();

        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texId);

        glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN);
        glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
        glVertex2f(0, 0);
        glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
        glVertex2f((float)texW, 0);
        glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
        glVertex2f((float)texW, (float)texH);
        glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
        glVertex2f(0, (float)texH);
        glEnd();

        glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

        glFlush();
        SDL_GL_SwapBuffers();       
    }   

    glDeleteTextures(1, &texId);

    IMG_Quit();
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The Linux build from the exact same source works. I have GL_TEXTURE_2D enabled.

Comment: @Rock: "The Linux build" That's irrelevant to your question. If it works, it doesn't mean it should work. "I have GL_TEXTURE_2D" There's no glEnable in your code fragment. Your code also does not generate mipmaps. that can be done using glGenerateMipmap, gluBuild2DMipmaps or glTexParameter(GL_GENERATE_MIPMAP). Why don't you post complete small example that demonstrates your problem? Your current code fragment doesn't even have any rendering routines.

Comment: @Rock: Look... extracting information from you or anybody else piece by piece isn't fun. Can't you simply make a very small complete SDL app that uses SDL_image to load texture and demonstrates the problem? Here's an ["SDL draft application"](http://pastebin.com/STqHBP64) for you to get started. Also read [sscce.org](http://sscce.org/) Just copy-paste your rendering/initialization code into the snippet, make sure it produces problem you experience, then upload result here. main.cpp will be enough. This way I'll be able to grab the damn thing, paste it into my compiler and debug.

Comment: @Rock: Without complete code fragment I(and pretty much anybody else) have to resort to fortune-telling, which takes 50 times longer for me to figure out what could possibly be wrong (out of infinite number of possible scenarios), and it takes longer for you to receive answer.

Comment: Take lesson06 from NeHe.gamedev.net in the Linux/SDL Version and compile with mingw. I only changed the projection as stated above and draw one more Quad.

Comment: @Rock: "Take lesson06 from NeHe" I think you misunderstand something. **I** don't have this problem, **you** do. So it is in your interest to provide relevant information. Failure to provide information means you don't want help. Since I'm not a tech support and, I'm not interested in going to a website with seizure-inducing colorscheme.